# Proof verification: The degree of a splitting field of a polynomial $f$ divides deg($f$) factorial

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

> Let $\mathbb K$ be a field, $\,f \in \mathbb K[X]$, $n :=$ *deg*(f).
>   Let $L$ be a splitting field of $\,f$ over $\mathbb K$. Then:
>
> 1. $[ L : \mathbb K] \,\mid\, n!$
> 2. $[ L : \mathbb K] = n! \implies f$ is irreducible

This is my attempt at proving the two statements in a single induction over $n$. Since $L$ is a splitting field $n \geq 1$.

---

**Base step** ($n = 1$):

- In this case $f$ has a single root $\alpha \in \mathbb K$ and $\frac{f}{l(f)}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb K$. Now $L = \mathbb K(\alpha) = \mathbb K \implies [L : \mathbb K] = 1$.

**Inductive step**($n \Rightarrow n+1$):

- Let $g \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ be an *irreducible* factor of $f$ (therefore $f = g \cdot h$ for some $h \in \mathbb{K}[X]$), with degree $m = $ deg($g$) $\in \{1, ..., n\}$. Let $\tilde{L}$ be the splitting field of $g$ over $\tilde{L}$ over $\mathbb{K}$.

  Now $L$ is also a splitting field of $\frac{f}{g}$ over $\tilde{L}$, because:

  1. $L$ is generated by the roots of $\frac{f}{g}$ over $\tilde{L}$, since $L$ is generated by the roots of $\,f$ over $\mathbb K$ and every root $\alpha$ of $f$ is either (i) a root $\frac{f}{g}$ or (ii) a root of $g$ and therefore already included in $\tilde{L}$.
  2. $\frac{f}{g}$ factors over $L$, since $f$ can be factored into linear terms over $L$.

  $$
  \implies \hspace{25px}[L : \mathbb K] = \underbrace{[L : \tilde{L}]}_{\,\mid\, m! \text{ (by induction)}}\cdot\hspace{15px}\underbrace{[\tilde{L} : \mathbb{K}]}_{\,\mid\, (n + 1 - m)! \text{ (by induction)}}
    $$

  Since for $a, b \in \mathbb N: a!\cdot b! \,\mid\, (a+b)!$ (and $a!\cdot b! < (a+b)!$ if $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$), it follows:
  $$
  \implies \hspace{25px}[L : \mathbb K] \,\mid\, (n + 1)! \\
  \text{(and}\hspace{15px} [L : \mathbb K] < (n + 1)\hspace{15px}\text{if $f$  wasn't irreducible already)}
    $$

I'm just wondering whether this proof is correct or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no need to consider separately the last two cases.Simply consider an irreducible factor of f (which may or may not coincide with f) and proceed as in the second case you did.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You are right. The separation is not necessary. Do you think it would be a good idea to edit the question for further readers or keep?

Comment: I think you need to switch the placements of the " $ \mid m! $ (by induction)" and "$  \mid (n+1-m)! $ (by induction)"

Comment: Degree of $g$ can go up to n+1, so the induction fails.